# C# .NET 4.5 - Entity Framework 6.0, MySQL Data Adapter assembly

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, wpf, entity-framework

I am trying to query against some users in a MySQL database- of course, when I acquired the packages to reference EntityFramework and use a MySQL connector, they are updated to version 6.0 now. This LINQ querying I've been practicing worked fine when I ran Entity Framework 5.0 with the MySQL data connector at the time several months ago in my VS 2012 IDE.

However, in my WPF application, when I JUST start to query the database through the appropriate entity, I get the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I was just starting to build this WPF application this week. Is there something I'm missing? Here's my code so far, with its config file.

app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
      </provider></providers>
  </entityFramework>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.9.8.0" newVersion="6.9.8.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
<connectionStrings><add name="otongadgethubEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/OTonGadgetHub.csdl|res://*/OTonGadgetHub.ssdl|res://*/OTonGadgetHub.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;password=abc123;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=otongadgethub&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings></configuration>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ChatClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void logIn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string nameRecord = "";
            string passRecord = "";

            if (UsernameField.Text == "" || UserPassField.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username and password required.");
            }
            else
            {
                using (otongadgethubEntities logCheck = new otongadgethubEntities())
                {
                    nameRecord = logCheck.users.First(a => a.username == UsernameField.Text).username;
                    if (nameRecord == UsernameField.Text)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Yes, this username exists.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the XAML for those that need to see the window too:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="ChatClient.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Icon="media/favicon.gif" Background="#FF3C3636" Foreground="{x:Null}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="logolayer2excompsoundfad_mp4"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.BorderBrush>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF6F6D95" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Window.BorderBrush>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource logolayer2excompsoundfad_mp4}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle x:Name="Menu" Fill="#755E5E83" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="273" Margin="35,23,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446" RadiusY="27.5" RadiusX="27.5"/>
        <Button Content="Log In" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="80" Margin="162,200,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource OTonButtonStyle1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="187" FontFamily="Impact" FontSize="26.667" Foreground="#FF1C045B" Click="logIn"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="UsernameField" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="204,57,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="[Username]" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="193" Background="#BD251E1E" UseLayoutRounding="False" FontFamily="Copperplate Gothic Light" FontSize="16">
            <TextBox.Foreground>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF1E2E95" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </TextBox.Foreground>
        </TextBox>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="16" Margin="98,57,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Username:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101" FontFamily="Copperplate Gothic Light" FontSize="16">
            <TextBlock.Foreground>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF0A1D5F" Offset="0.374"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF6E7FB9" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </TextBlock.Foreground>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBox x:Name="UserPassField" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="204,99,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="[Password]" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="193" Background="#BD251E1E" UseLayoutRounding="False" FontFamily="Copperplate Gothic Light" FontSize="16">
            <TextBox.Foreground>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF1E2E95" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </TextBox.Foreground>
        </TextBox>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="16" Margin="98,99,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Password:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101" FontFamily="Copperplate Gothic Light" FontSize="16">
            <TextBlock.Foreground>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF0A1D5F" Offset="0.374"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF6E7FB9" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </TextBlock.Foreground>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Any thoughts???

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem had to do with (as I read in other articles) the fact that an assembly did not match with others. First, I removed Entity Framework 6.0 and as a result the depending MySQL adapters with NuGet. Then, I made sure to ONLY add the MySQL.Data.Entities, as all relevant depending assemblies are added automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in your WebConfig

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.9.8.0" newVersion="6.9.9.0" />
```